# Is it necessary to use Print inside a Block?

Tags: replacement, variable, localization

If I use a `Block` with variables already used and ask it to `Solve` an equation inside the `Block`, it uses the values given outside the `Block`. For instance, this gives a numeric answer:

```
R = 1; L = 3;
Block[{R, L, x}, Solve[R + L x == 0, x] ]

(* {{x -> -(1/3)}} *)
```

But, if I ask it to `Print` the result everything is fine:

```
R = 1; L = 3;
Block[{R, L, x}, Print[Solve[R + L x == 0, x]] ]

(* {{x->-(R/L)}} *)
```

On the second line of the "Details" of `Block` it says that

> When you execute a block, values assigned to x, y, ... are cleared.

So I would expect that anything executing inside a `Block` would work with cleared (empty) variables and return an expression, not a number obtained with values given to the variables outside the `Block`. Is this supposed to happen? Must I always use a `Print` command for `Block` to localize the variables?

Comment: This is behaving just as I would expect.  Inside the `Block`, `R` and `L` have no value assigned to them.  Outside the block, they take their global values.  `Print` outputs the result  before `R` and `L` revert to their global values.  Without knowing what you are trying to achieve, it is difficult to suggest what you should do.

Comment: @mikado Sorry, I've edited my question to reflect what I was expecting to get from ´Block´.

Comment: Inside the `Block` the variables are cleared.  Outside the `Block` they return to the old values.  If you don't want the old values any more, use `Clear[R, L]`.

Comment: @mikado I don't want the values given outside `Block` to affect the functions written inside it, but after I'm finished with the `Block` estructure, I want the values to return to the old values. That is the definition of `Block`: "Block allows you to set up an environment in which the values of variables can temporarily be changed." and "When you execute a block, values assigned to x, y,... are cleared. When the execution of the block is finished, the original values of these symbols are restored." But this appears to not be working unless I use `Print` inside the `Block`.

Comment: @mikado After reading lericr's answer now I see that you were giving me a similar answer but I wasn't versed enough in Mathematica's inner workings to understand it. I am sorry I couldn't understand you earlier. But now I do so, thank you for your effort!

Comment: In learning Mathemtatica, I found the scoping rules one of the most difficult parts to understand, so I sympathise with your difficulties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I don't want the values given outside Block to affect the functions written inside it, but after I'm finished with the Block estructure, I want the values to return to the old values.

That is exactly what is happening here. Don't forget that the evaluation engine is still running. When the Block is finished, the expression it emits is `{{x->-(R/L)}}`, but that expression now gets its turn to be evaluated, and now that we're outside of the Block, the "old" values for R and L are available and so are used.

Mathematica doesn't know that you want to stop evaluating an expression unless you tell it. To tell it to stop evaluating, you can use any of the various Hold* expressions, Unevaluated, Inactive/Inactivate, Defer, etc. But which of those you want depends on your use case.

Just throwing something together with no real reason:

```
Block[{R, L, x}, HoldForm[Evaluate[Solve[R + L x == 0, x]]]]
```

Comment: I think I now understand what is happening. The problem for me was that I didn't know that after the `Block` returns an expression, then "the expression gets its turn to be evaluated". It seems weird to me that this evaluation happens without me requesting it, but I guess this behavior must have its uses for someone... Thank you very much for such clear explanation, lericr!! I will accept the answer soon, if no one gives another explanation.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I'm sorry if this question is stupid but, if it is not too much to ask: how do you know (what should I look for in the documentation to know) that the `Block` estructure will be executed again after it has returned an expression? For instance, does an Ìf` statement get evaluated again after it has returned the appropriate values?

Comment: Evaluation continues until the result no longer changes. Block isn’t a special case. This is just how Mathematica inherently works.

Comment: It's not that the Block was evaluated again, it's just that Block was effecively replaced with its result, and we just continued on with evaluation from there. An `If` statement does not get evaluated again, but whatever result it produces will be the next thing that gets evaluated.

Comment: Consider this: `If[True, 2, 3]*10`. The `If` is just an expression, and once the evaluator gets ahold of it, it will want to replace it if it can. In this case it can, and so `If[True, 2, 3]` goes poof, and becomes `2`. But that `2` is still part of something larger that needs to evaluate, and so we keep going. We get `20`, and we keep going. It turns out that raw "atoms" like this evaluate to themselves, so we get `20` again, and now the evaluator realizes that it needs to stop, because otherwise it'd get into an infinite recursion.

Comment: This example might be clearer: `x = 0; If[False, x += 5, x += 99]`. Notice that neither of the updates can be allowed to evaluate before the predicate evaluates (`If` is very special in this regard, but that helps me illustrate the issue). This is one `CompoundExpression` expression, and it evaluates in sequence, so `x` was set to `0` right off the bat. Now we tackle the `If`. The `False` tells us that we'll replace the entire `If` with `x+=99`. And we keep going...

Comment: We next replace the whole `CompoundExpression` with `x+=99`, because `CompoundExpression` evalutes to its final "term". Next, `x+=99` has the side effect of setting `x` to `0+99`, and it evalutes to `0+99`, which evalutes to `99`, then `99`, then we're done.

Comment: Amazing, lericr!!! I've learned so much from your explanation and I will be always grateful to you for it. Thank you very, very much!!! I've finally accepted your answer as a small reward. Truly, all these answers are one masterpiece of explanation!!